# BrowserSync starts with NO access URL's listed

Tags: angular, npm, gulp, yeoman, browser-sync

I just installed a scaffolding project from Yeoman (ng-fullstack) and only selected the client side options. It installed fine but when I run "gulp", all tasks run without error and launches http://localhost:3000. This never resolves a website and in the console output I get:

[image]

The line of code that runs browserSync looks like this:

```
browserSync({proxy: "http://localhost:3333", reloadDelay: 1000});
```

Any ideas of why this is not working correctly? I am not too familiar with browserSync just yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using powershell? I may have encountered the same problem. In my case the Access Urls are actually printed, but invisible due to coloring.

You can find out by copy/pasting the Access Urls in a text-editor and check their values.

Comment: That's absolutely wild, as selecting the text doesn't show it either!

Comment: OMG, that is so annoying - I didn't even think to check that. It is 2.5 years later and still an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You also could revert the powershell window to use as legacy console. Right-click on the title bar of your powershell window, choose "Properties", and then click on "Use legacy console".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this same thing happened to me. It is because of PowerShell's color settings. Using "legacy mode" in PowerShell's Properties did nothing to help with this problem.

Copying and pasting works as noted in Erik's answer because the info is there.

I simply changed my PowerShell background color to a different color. Anything brighter than the default (dark) blue should help. I like a very subtle neon pink.

Right-click on the PowerShell window title bar and select 'Properties'. Then select the 'Colors' tab. There you will find the options to customize PowerShell's display palette.

PowerShell Properties Screenshot[image]